# Replace .toString() single quotes with double quotes

Tags: node.js, couchdb

Perhaps a strange request, but I'm using CouchDB views, which requires a string to be surrounded by double quotes.

This works:

> ?key=["test","234"]

This won't work:

> ?key=['test','234']

So in my NodeJS application, I'm trying to build up the correct key to pass to CouchDB

```
var key1 = "test";
var key2 = "234";

{ key: [key1, key2] }
```

This always comes out as

```
{ key: [ 'test', '234' ] }
```

Is there any effective way to get my desired output? (double quotes)

Comment: @br3w5 it isn't, I'm not asking how to replace quotes in a string. But rather how to output a string with double quotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CouchDB does not need double-quotes per se; it needs **JSON-encoded** parameters.

That's good news for you! Just build your key however you like in JavaScript:

```
var key = [
    'test',
    '234'
]
```

And then JSON-encode it before sending to CouchDB:

```
key = JSON.stringify(key) // Result: the string '["test","234"]'
```

Comment: That's strange, as I did try that before, but it yielded no results. Perhaps there was something else going on, but I assumed the quotes where the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear if you want to pass an object with the keys or a string representing the object.
If you pass a string, why don't you use JSON.stringify which uses double quotes?

```
var key1 = "test";
var key2 = "234";
JSON.stringify({key: [key1, keys]})
```

This will produde:
{"key": ["test", "234"]}

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but I imagine you could use String.fromCharCode(34) for the double quotes instead of typing them directly. So

var key1 = String.fromCharCode(34) + test + String.fromCharCode(34);

Or even

var doubleQuote = String.fromCharCode(34);
var key1 = doubleQuote + test + doubleQuote;

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your node.js app

```
var key1 = '"test"';
var key2 = '"234"';
```

this will result in:

```
{ 
   key: 
   [ 
      '"test"', 
      '"234"' 
   ] 
}
```

I havn't used CouchDB, perhaps this would solve your problem.